# Install Ubuntu alongside windows

Tags: installation

When we install ubuntu along with windows 7 do we need any other drivers other than what we have installed on windows?

Answer (score 0):

Driver's for Ubuntu is different from Windows, you might not find all the drivers you have for Windows, graphics drivers can be installed using "Software Updater", others you may have to search online in you computer's manufacturer's website.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu comes packaged with generic drivers for a lot of hardware available so all your hardware will probably work out-of the-box. In special circumstances, you will need to install proprietary drivers (this is for instancey the case for NVidia graphics cards). You can enable these after the install.

If you are worried that some special hardware might not work, there are several programms that list hardware that will work under Ubuntu. You can find them via [this page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupport)